# Loop within dataframe subset

Tags: r, loops, subset

This is probably a basic question in R, but I am trying to loop data within subsets of a larger data frame. I have added the 'data=sub240' line within the 'while' command, but this leads to a brackets error, which I suspect is indicative of a larger problem.  Can anyone tell me how to run a loop on a subset of a dataframe? I don't think it is relevant, but I am using the 'optiscale' package within the loop.

```
{while (rsquared.differ > .00001 && niter <= 30 && data=sub240) {
niter <- niter + 1
reg.os<- lm(dvar.os ~ index.os + educ.os)

rsquared.differ <- summary(reg.os)$r.squared - previous.rsquared
previous.rsquared <- summary(reg.os)$r.squared

record <- c(record, niter, summary(reg.os)$r.squared, rsquared.differ)

if (rsquared.differ > .00001) {
dvar.pred <- predict(reg.os)

opscaled.dvar <- opscale(intknow, dvar.pred, level = 1, process = 1)
dvar.os <- opscaled.dvar$os

intknow240.pred <- (dvar.os - (reg.os$coefficients[1] +
(reg.os$coefficients[4]*educ.os)
))*
(1/reg.os$coefficients[2])

opscaled.intknow240 <- opscale(anes$intknow, intknow240.pred, level = 1, process = 1)
intknow240.os <- opscaled.intknow240$os


}}
```

Comment: You haven't even mentioned what language/technology this is. You should add a tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = sub240` is an assignment statement. You can assign things on their own line or in function definitions and calls, but you can only provide logical statements in a `while` loop definition. If you want logical equality, you need `==`. But unless `data` changes in the loop AND you would like that to be a condition for the loop to break, then you don't want that inside your `while` statement. But generally, there is no need for that statement anyway. The way scoping works in R, the loop should still be able to access `data` if it is defined outside the loop.

Also, I'm pretty sure you don't need the bracket before `while`, only after. As your code stands, it won't run because that bracket is unclosed: You have three open brackets (before `while`, after `while`, and after `if`), but only two close brackets (that I could find, anyway).

Try something like this:

```
data <- sub240
while(rsquared.differ > 0.00001 && niter <=30){
    # do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it was straightforward, but couldn't find the answer anywhere.